# Android - How to execute a class on onAnimationEnd

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation

I have an AsyncTask that is created in `onCreate()` it is called `GatherText()` I have an animation that slides a TextView out of view. When that animation ends I want it to call the AsyncTask.

Here is a basic idea of my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 class GatherText extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            } 

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            } 

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            }//end onPostExecute

        }//end GatherText Asynctask


   }//end onCreate


    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if(animation == slideout){
           //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
                    new GatherText().execute();
               }
    }//End onAnimationEnd


}//end Main Activity
```

In the `onAnimationEnd()` method I receive an error that says `GatherText() can not be resolved to a type`. How can I call `GatherText()` outside of `onCreate`?

Comment: does that even compile ? why is GatherText inside onCreate?

Comment: Where else would it go?

Comment: put it outside onCreate, this is a scope problem

Answer (score 0):

Put your asynctask class outside of onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



 }//end onCreate

class GatherText extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        } 

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        } 

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        }//end onPostExecute

    }//end GatherText Asynctask


@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if(animation == slideout){
       gathertext = new GatherText();
       new GatherText().execute();
    }
}//End onAnimationEnd
```